# when i click on single product getting error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params') in ProductScreen.js . mern ecommerce site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

i am tying to create ecommerce website using mern. for the homepage all products are showing but  whenever i click on single product the product page is not loading . Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params'),

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Product from '../components/Product';
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'


const HomeScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
  const { loading, error, products } = productList


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
  }, [dispatch])


  return <>
    <h1 className='text-center my-3'> Latest Products</h1>
    {loading ? (
      <Loader />
    ) : error ? (
      <Message variant='danger'> {error} </Message>
    ) : (
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    )}
  </>;
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

ProductScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions'


const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails)
  const { loading, error, product,id } = productDetails
 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProductDetails(match.params.id))
  }, [dispatch, match, id])

  return (
    <>
      <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
        Go Back
      </Link>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid />
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant='flush'>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating
                  value={product.rating}
                  text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                />
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Price: ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                Description: {product.description}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
              <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Price:</Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Status:</Col>
                    <Col>
                      {product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out Of Stock'}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Button
                    className='btn-block'
                    type='button'
                    disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                  >
                    Add To Cart
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen"



function App() {
  return (

   
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
        <Routes>
             <Route path="/" element={ <HomeScreen />} exact />
             <Route path="/product/:id" element={ <ProductScreen />}  />
        </Routes>
        </Container>
        </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

productActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products')

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}

export const listProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST })

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
}
```

productConstants.js

```
export const PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST = 'PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST'
export const PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS = 'PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS'
export const PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL = 'PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL'


export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST = "PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST";
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS = "PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS";
export const PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL = "PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL";
```

productReducers.js

```
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] }
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload }
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const productDetailsReducer = (
  state = { product: { reviews: [] } },
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, ...state }
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, product: action.payload }
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { notFound, errorHandler } from './middleware/errorMiddleware.js'
import connectDB from './config/db.js'
import productRoutes from './routes/productRoutes.js'


dotenv.config()


connectDB()


const app = express();



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello from the root application URL...')
});

app.use('/api/products', productRoutes)

app.use( notFound )

app.use( errorHandler)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, console.log( `server is running IN  ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a property of a variable in ProductScreen.js which is not initialised by you. Very likely that is `match.params.id`.

Comment: please help with code. i am not getting your point